# Sketch $\log(|z|)= -2\arg(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

I believe I can solve for z:

Let $z=re^{i\theta}$, then
$\log(|z|)=-2\arg(z)$ becomes
$$\log(r)=-2\theta$$
->

$$z=e^{-2\theta}[\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)], 0<\theta \leq \pi$$

But I don't know how to use this fact to sketch the whole set of solutions. Since both $\log(|z|)$ and $\arg(z)$ are real-valued, I tried to do it like this:

For $x>0$
$$\log(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})=-2\Bigl(\tan{\frac{y}{x}}\Bigr)^{-1}$$

->
$$x^2+y^2=e^{-4\tan\left(\tfrac{y}{x}\right)^{-1}}$$

but I have no idea how to proceed. And this is only the case when $x>0$. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $z=re^{i\theta}$ the relation
$$\log |z|=-2\arg z$$
will be $r=e^{-2\theta}$ which shows a spiral shape named [logarithmic spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_spiral).

Comment: yes, thats what I meant in my answer, I lost the "-" sign. but if I never met the logarithmic spiral, how do I know the answer. and moreover how do I sketch the region in the cartesian plane?

Comment: See the link. With some values for $\theta$ you can draw it's shape in every interval.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polar+plot+r%3De%5E(-2theta),+theta%3D0+to+8+pi